# What should I do if two modules share the same name?

Tags: haskell

I have two packages that provide modules with the same name. When I try to load the module I get an error

> Ambiguous interface for ....: It was found in multiple packages.

What should I do to resolve this?

To be specific, both the `cryptonite` package and `crypto-api` package provide modules with the name `Crypto.Random`. How can I specify which package I want to load the module from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `PackageImports` language pragma and explicitly pick the package you mean in your import statement like so:

```
import "cryptonite" Crypto.Random
```

Alternatively if you have both installed but are only using one of them, you could explicitly list the dependencies you use in a `cabal` file and build via `cabal`.

Answer (score 13):

If you happen to be using **ghc >= 8.2** and **cabal-install >= 2.0**, another option is renaming the conflicting modules in the [`mixins`](http://blog.ezyang.com/2017/01/try-backpack-cabal-packages/) section of the cabal file:

```
  build-depends:       base >=4.10 && <4.11,
                       cryptonite >= 0.24,
                       crypto-api >= 0.13.2
  mixins:
                       cryptonite (Crypto.Random as CryptoniteCrypto.Random),
                       crypto-api (Crypto.Random as CryptoAPICrypto.Random)
```

You can then import the renamed modules:

```
module Main where

import CryptoniteCrypto.Random
import CryptoAPICrypto.Random
```

One thing to take into account when renaming this way is that modules that haven't been explicitly renamed become inaccessible.

In fact, ability to rename modules [seems to exist since **GHC 7.10**](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-library-reexported-modules), through the [-package](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-thinning-and-renaming) flag and the **reexported-modules** cabal section. **reexported-modules** works at declaration-time (when publishing a package) while **mixins** works at use-time (when depending on a package).