# How do I use PackageImports properly in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want to do testing in ghci and I'm running into problems with similarly named modules in different packages (this is basically a continuation of my previous question: [What should I do if two modules share the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110907/what-should-i-do-if-two-modules-share-the-same-name/47111418#47111418))

The packages in question are `crypto-api`, `cryptonite`, and `DRBG`. They all provides modules involving `Crypto.Random`. I'm using `PackageImports` in ghci to work fix this issue.

However, it seems that the order of using `PackageImports` is important.

This works (in ghci):

```
:set -XPackageImports
import Crypto.Random.DRBG
import "crypto-api" Crypto.Random
```

This does not work:

```
:set -XPackageImports
import "crypto-api" Crypto.Random
import Crypto.Random.DRBG  -- Error!
```

Also this does not work:

```
:set -XPackageImports
import "crypto-api" Crypto.Random
import "DRBG" Crypto.Random.DRBG -- Error!
```

The error that appears is:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
Ambiguous interface for ‘Crypto.Random’:
  it was found in multiple packages:
  crypto-api-0.13.2 cryptonite-0.23
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: What's the error message? And how about using this method "import Mod as Foo" to give three modules different names? Just a guess.

Comment: @JohnnyLiao, I added the error message that I get. I also tried importing the module with `as` but I got the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way is to avoid `PackageImports` and instead rename the packages when starting ghci, using the [-package](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html) option:

```
ghci -package "crypto-api (Crypto.Random as A)" -package "cryptonite (Crypto.Random as B)"
```

Once in ghci, you could import the renamed modules:

```
Prelude> import A
Prelude A> import B
Prelude A B>
```

---

The syntax `-package "crypto-api (Crypto.Random as A)"` makes only the `Crypto.Random` module available to ghci, but not the other modules in the package.

According to the [Thinning and renaming modules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-thinning-and-renaming) section of the GHC user guide:

> We also support renaming of modules, in case you need to refer to both
>   modules simultaneously; this is supporting by writing OldModName as
>   NewModName, e.g. -package "base (Data.Bool as Bool). You can also
>   write -package "base with (Data.Bool as Bool) to include all of the
>   original bindings (e.g. the renaming is strictly additive).

So perhaps it's better to write the options like `-package "crypto-api with (Crypto.Random as A)"` to maintain access to all the modules.

---

Using `PackageImports` instead of thinning and renaming modules has the problem that it makes the source code dependent on the precise packages in which imported modules live. If a module changes packages that breaks the program.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect that to work at all?

```
:set -XPackageImports
import "crypto-api" Crypto.Random
import Crypto.Random.DRBG  -- Error!
import "DRBG" Crypto.Random.DRBG -- Error!
```

You have imported the DRBG module twice and from the same package.  From your question I thought you'd want to get the `Crypto.Random` modules from crypto-api and cryptonite but I don't see any attempt to use cryptonite at all here.

Just so we're clear, I can reproduce the error I think you were getting via GHCi:

```
Prelude> :set -XPackageImports
Prelude> import "crypto-api" Crypto.Random as OriginalRandom
Prelude OriginalRandom> import "cryptonite" Crypto.Random as ConflictRandom

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Ambiguous module name ‘Crypto.Random’:
      it was found in multiple packages:
      crypto-api-0.13.2 cryptonite-0.24
```

But it all works when you load it from a file so this is just a bug and can be avoided:

```
% cat t.hs
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

import "crypto-api" Crypto.Random as OriginalRandom
import "cryptonite" Crypto.Random as ConflictRandom
import Crypto.Random.DRBG -- This only appears in one package
% ghci t.hs
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/tommd/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( t.hs, interpreted )
Ok, 1 module loaded.
*Main>
```

Notice that DRBG is not part of this discussion.  It doesn't have any conflicting modules names with anything on hackage as far as I know.

Comment: I've edited my initial question because I guess I didn't write it clearly. I wasn't trying to import `DRBG` twice, I was just trying to show that two ways of importing `DRBG` with `PackageImports` didn't work. The `cryptonite` package isn't directly involved with the error, but the reason I'm using `PackageImports` in the first place is that `cryptonite` and `crypto-api` have shared module names, so I think it's worth mentioning. I know that I can import them from a file but I want to know if this can be done if ghci without causing a bug.