# Deprecate or shadow a module or function from a third-party library

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, deprecation-warning

In our project (a cabal project with executable and library sections), we sometimes implement "safer" or improved versions of standard functions from e.g. `base` and export a tweaked version of the module in a new namespace, e.g.

```
module Data.Foo.Extended (module Data.Foo, foo) where
import Data.Foo hiding (foo)
foo = someSaferVersionOfFoo
```

This allows us to use a better API without committing to a big refactor (we can move to `Data.Foo.Extended` in other parts of the codebase incrementally).

But once we decide to move to `*.Extended` everywhere we'd like a way to issue a warning when the legacy (standard) module is imported (or perhaps when certain functions are used), so that the change sticks.

`DEPRECATED` pragma won't work since we don't own the code we're deprecating

Is there a clever way to:

- hide a module from the project (except for our shim)?
- shadow a module with our own?
- issue some kind of warning (i.e. make the `DEPRECATED` idea work)?

Comment: Hm, maybe this is possible with a new shadowing `library` section in the cabal file, along with PackageImports?

Comment: I would probably go about it with an external tool that would be run during CI. The tool could be as simple as `grep "import Data.Foo "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mixins`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-mixins) field in Cabal files (I believe Stack also supports it) can be used to rename, hide, or shadow modules.

For example, assuming we have a convenience library or package with a `MyPrelude` module, we can shadow the standard `Prelude` of another library in this way:

```
library
  -- in this library, Prelude is really MyPrelude
  exposed-modules:     Foo 
  hs-source-dirs:      lib
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       
    base ^>=4.12.0.0,
    myprelude
  mixins:
    -- switcheroo happens here
    base hiding (Prelude),
    myprelude (MyPrelude as Prelude),

-- internal convenience library, could be an external package
library myprelude
  -- MyPrelude uses Prelude normally, might even re-export it
  exposed-modules:     MyPrelude 
  hs-source-dirs:      lib-prelude
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base ^>=4.12.0.0
```

Also `build-depends` and `mixins` fields can be put into [common stanzas](https://vrom911.github.io/blog/common-stanzas) in order to avoid repetition when shadowing the same module across multiple executables/libraries:

```
common tweaked-prelude
  build-depends:       
    base ^>=4.12.0.0,
    myprelude
  mixins:
    base hiding (Prelude),
    myprelude (MyPrelude as Prelude),

library
  import: tweaked-prelude
  exposed-modules:     Foo 
  hs-source-dirs:      lib
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Comment: `mixins` is also a (better) alternative to `-XPackageImports` for handling module name collisions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111418/1364288

Comment: But this is not quite the same thing, is it? The OP didn't want to instantly replace all `Data.Foo` imports with `Data.Foo.Extended`. As far as I understood the question, the signature of the "improved" `foo` would be different from the "regular" variety, so you'd have to go through and modify the consuming code, which is the why the OP said "move ... incrementally".

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thanks for your reply, I was probably unclear: I _do_ want to shadow and replace the standard module, but only at some later time. I was trying to describe a workflow that doesn't require commiting to big refactor at first (you can initially just define the Extended module and import it where you want to use it).

Comment: @jberryman That's exactly what I said in my comment though, isn't it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin In that case it would be enough to render the original module inaccesible using `hiding`, without changing the name of the extended module.

Comment: @danidiaz no, the original module cannot be rendered inaccessible. It has to remain accessible for a prolonged period of time (days, weeks, maybe even months?) while the _incremental_ migration is in progress.